# Unbranding/debranding

Tags: 8.1

HTC 8s is not going to get a GDR1 WP8.1 update ever in future. Is it possible to debrand device to get this update? I know that debranding is to remove carrier software, but is there something similar to that? If anything is unclear, ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update: Yes!**

[Microsoft have just made the latest update to Windows 8.1.1](http://blogs.windows.com/bloggingwindows/2014/09/24/new-update-for-windows-phone-preview-for-developers/) (ie. WP 8.1 Update 1) available on all phones including the HTC 8x and 8s

Your phone will have to enrolled in the Dev Preview programme to get this update, so [please read this handy guide from WP Central which explains everything](http://www.wpcentral.com/how-sign-windows-phone-81-preview-developers).

Carrier branding doesn't change the model of the phone (only default language and pre-installed apps), and in this case, that's the important bit.